# Ft232h doesn't run as a normal user , it requires root user (redhat unix)

Tags: rhel

I'm using the `ftdixx` driver and `ftdi.so` file to communicate with `ft232h` module. `FT_Open(iport, &fthandle)` function doesn't work with normal user. If it is root user, it is working and opening the port. In normal user mode, it is failing with segmentation fault in `FT_Open(iport, &fthandle)` function. So what could be cause of this issue.

```
int main()
{
FT_STATUS ftstatus;
FT_HANDLE fthandle;
int iport =0;
DWORD libversion = 0;

ftstatus = FT_GetLibraryVersion(&libversion)
if(ftstatus != FT_OK)
{
}

ftstatus = FT_Open(iport, &fthandle)
if(ftstatus != FT_OK)
{
}
return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Comment: Permission issue for the port. If it is an USB FTDI device then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419691/accessing-a-usb-device-with-libusb-1-0-as-a-non-root-user)

Comment: @ClausAndersen it doesnt worked out for me . already I had tried changing the udev rule set.

Comment: I do not have any better ideas. Nevertheless I would add that udev rule to the question - it might be related